# LINQ expressions?

Tags: php, linq

Is there a way to use LINQ Expressions in PHP? 
For example, in C# I can do the following:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>()
{
    "Francisco",
    "Ronald",
    "Araújo",
    "Barbosa"
};

var oneName = names.Where(x => x.Equals("Ronald")).FirstOrDefault();
```

And in PHP, how would I do something like the following?

```
names **.Where** (x => x.Equals("Ronald")) **.FirstOrDefault()**;
```

Comment: Do you want to use [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) or [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)?

Comment: I want to use LINQ. Is it possible?

Comment: http://phplinq.codeplex.com/ take a look at this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a few PHP libraries that mimic the functionalities of LINQ. Examples are:

- [PHPLinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/)
- [YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo)
- [PHINQ](https://code.google.com/p/phinq/)
- [PINQ](https://github.com/TimeToogo/Pinq)

In PHPLinq the code would look like this:

```
$names = array("Francisco", "Ronald", "Araújo", "Barbosa"); 
$oneName = from('$name')->in($names)
            ->where('$x => $x == "Ronald"')
            ->firstOrDefault('$name');
```

Or with PINQ which takes a different approach with PHP 5.3+ closures:

```
$oneName = \Pinq\Traversable::from($names)
            ->where(function ($x) { return $x == 'Ronald'; })
            ->first();
```

Comment: All these seems to be abandoned...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend PHPLinq because it's not what you're used to in .NET, even if it *looks like* LINQ. The reasons are:

1. The order of calls is fixed (the result may not be what you expect).
2. It's not truly lazy.

The strong point of PHPLinq is that it's <s>the only</s> LINQ implementation for PHP which supports databases. It's no longer the only one, TimeToogo's PINQ supports databases too, but at the time of writing, PINQ's only LINQ provider is MySQL demo.

If all you need is querying arrays and objects in the code, you should use [YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo) instead*. If you need support for databases, the only option is PHPLinq, but be aware of its limitations. I strongly suggest using popular production-ready alternatives, there're enough ORMs, ARs etc.

Example using YaLinqo:

```
$names = array("Francisco", "Ronald", "Araújo", "Barbosa"); 
$oneName = from($names)->where('$x ==> $x == "Ronald"')->firstOrDefault();
```

<sub>* YaLinqo is developed by me.</sub>

Comment: Can you add support for databases to YoLinqo?

Comment: @Pangamma It's out of YaLinqo's scope. YaLinqo's priorities are speed, simplicity and diversity of transformations, two of which don't play well with DB layer (good LINQ to SQL transformation is very complex, and DB functionality limits the number of transformations), so it's strictly LINQ to objects by design. TimeToogo's [Pinq](TimeToogo/Pinq), another LINQ port, supports databases, but as a result, it's much more complex, more limited and significantly slower. Its only DB provider is a demo for MySQL, so I guess DB feature isn't production-ready.

Comment: @Pangamma At the core, there're two problems. First, writing a provider generating sensible SQL is hard, really hard. Second, PHP doesn't provide expression support like C#, and it won't happen anytime soon (I hope we'll see lambdas at least). Considering this, LINQ to DB won't happen in PHP in the near future, if at all. You should look for alternative solutions.

Comment: Fair enough. There is value to simplicity when you don't want a lot of overhead.